# UDP Socket, doesn't work the 1st time, works the 2nd

Tags: c, sockets, udp

Trying to build the skeleton for a simple program receiving data from a udp socket. I will get a received message however, the message never pops up, if i try to resend the message, the message then pops up but the same problem occurs over and over. I am sure I am missing something dumb, but can't place it.

```c
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int shared_sock,n, received, receivelen;
struct sockaddr_in receivesocket;
socklen_t len;
char mesg[100];
unsigned char assist_id[] = {0x18, 0xDE, 0x1B};



int main()
{

   shared_sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
   /* my address */
   memset(&receivesocket, 0, sizeof(receivesocket));
   receivesocket.sin_family = AF_INET;
   receivesocket.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   receivesocket.sin_port = htons(11000);

   receivelen = sizeof(receivesocket);
   if (bind(shared_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &receivesocket, receivelen) < 0) {
      perror("bind");
      return 1;
   }
   memset(mesg, 0, 100);
   while(true){
      if ((received = recvfrom(shared_sock, mesg, 100, 0, NULL, NULL)) < 0){
         perror("recvfrom");
         return 1;
      }
      printf("Received the following %d:\n", received);
      printf("%s",mesg);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This program compiles and runs correctly for me (under MacOS/X) -- sending a UDP packet to 127.0.0.1:11000 from another program on the same host causes this program to print "Received the following [blah]:" every time I send a packet.  If you are sending your UDP packets from a different host, perhaps your firewall is playing games with you?  You might try disabling it if it's enabled.

Comment: Try fflush(stdout); after printing it.

Comment: Are you getting the `printf` message from after sending the first message?

Comment: I'll get the first print statement but then afterwards it is blank

But if i then resend the message while leaving the program up, the message shows up and then directly after it the print statement is printed again

Comment: Just added the fflush(stdout) and now it works just the way it should!

Thanks!